# Select with CAST: Success; Update with CAST: Failure

Tags: mysql

I do not understand the following works

```
SELECT price, CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) FROM orders;
```

But the update fails with both:

```
UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2));
UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS CHAR(20));
```

with the error:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect DECIMAL value '0' for column '' at row -1
```

The column `price` is `TEXT`

In my understanding, the `SELECT` should do the exact same as the `UPDATE`

Comment: You missed a `)` in your update query. Also, what if price was empty for some row, or null?

Comment: @vivek_23 Sorry for the `)`, fixed now. Price is `NULL` for some rows. But I get the same issue even with `WHERE price IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In select  you just show the resul of cast as decimal in update  you save a decimal in a not numeric
Try casting the resul as a string to

```
    UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(CAST(ifnull(price,0) AS DECIMAL(10,2) AS char(20));
```

or could be you have a value that can't be cast as  decimal eg some space  for this you can check the different condition using a case

```
    UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(CAST(
         CASE when price IS NULL THEN 0 
              when trim(price) ='' THEN 0 
                ELSE price 
              END )  AS DECIMAL(10,2) AS char(20));
```

Comment: I get the exact same issue with this, but you cannot set `VARCHAR` you should use `CHAR` instead.

Comment: Is it MySQL compatible ? I get a `"IFNULL" invalid at this position`

Answer (score 0):

As you state:

> The column `price` is `TEXT`.

So in your first example, you're casting a text value to a decimal value.

Your second query (the update) is problematic, because you're trying to update a text attribute to the decimal version of itself. When you update a text value, there's no need to cast it to a decimal.

Your statement,

> In my understanding, the SELECT should do the exact same as the UPDATE

is flawed: With `SELECT`, you're pulling data from your data for consumption by some other process. That may involve casting an attribute to another data type.

With an `UPDATE` statement, the new value should be the same data type as your attribute. Since `price` is text, the new value should be text (which is why you shouldn't be updating the attribute to a DECIMAL version of itself).

Answer (score 0):

You may have an empty value somewhere

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `price` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO orders (price) VALUES (''); -- Empty value
```

No errors:

```
SELECT price, CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) FROM orders;
```

Error:

```
UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

No Error:

```
UPDATE orders SET price = CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) WHERE price <> ''
```

Comment: You may also need to `trim()` it at times I think. For example, what if any row had `...196.78....` (assume that `.` is a space).